# Question on continued fraction?

Tags: continued-fractions

I have seen in wikipedia that irrational numbers have infinite continued fraction but I also found $$1=\frac{2}{3-\frac{2}{3-\ddots}}$$ so my question is that does that mean $1$ is irrational because it can be written as an infinite continued fraction?

Comment: Irrational numbers have infinite decimal expansion. But so does $\frac13$.

Answer (score 3):

The theorem about irrationals and and infinite continued fractions is for **simple** continued fractions. See [here](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Continued_fraction)

Answer (score 0):

No it does not, since the logic behind the statement is

$x$ irrational $\implies$ $x$ can be written as an infinite continued fraction.

However, this does not necessarily mean that rationals *cannot* have an infinite continued fraction.

Comment: But in fact the *simple* continued fraction is infinite if and only if the number is irrational.

Comment: I guess i get it now